# How to dynamically create select input using JS

Tags: javascript, frontend, backend, materialize

So I am trying to build an app where you can add shifts to a web page. I can add

elements and text inputs to the page, however the select inputs are not showing up on the page

**What it is supposed to look like**
[image]

**What it actually looks like**
[image]

As you can see all other elements, besides selects, are working fine...

**Code**

```
var newShift = $(
        "<div id='Shift" + numOfShifts + "'>" +
        "<p class='white-text'>Shift" + numOfShifts + "</p>" +
        "<div class='row'>" +
        "<div class='col s4 offset-s2'>" +
            "<div class='row'>" +
                "<p class='white-text'>Shift Starts at:</p>" +
                "<div class='input-field col s6'>" +
                    "<select id='shiftStart'" + numOfShifts + "' class='start-hour front'>" +
                        "<option value='' disable selected>Hour</option>" +
                        "<option value='00'>12am</option>" +
                        "<option value='01'>1am</option>" +
                        "<option value='02'>2am</option>" + 
                        "<option value='03'>3am</option>" +
                        "<option value='04'>4am</option>" +
                        "<option value='05'>5am</option>" +
                        "<option value='06'>6am</option>" +
                        "<option value='07'>7am</option>" +
                        "<option value='08'>8am</option>" +
                        "<option value='09'>9am</option>" +
                        "<option value='10'>10am</option>" +
                        "<option value='11'>11am</option>" +
                        "<option value='12'>12pm</option>" +
                        "<option value='13'>1pm</option>" +
                        "<option value='14'>2pm</option>" +
                        "<option value='15'>3pm</option>" +
                        "<option value='16' > 4pm</option >" +
                        "<option value='17'>5pm</option>" +
                        "<option value='18'>6pm</option>" +
                        "<option value='19'>7pm</option>" +
                        "<option value='20'>8pm</option>" +
                        "<option value='21'>9pm</option>" +
                        "<option value='22'>10pm</option>" +
                        "<option value='23'>11pm</option>" +
                    "</select>" +
                "</div>" +
                "<div class='input-field col s6'>" +
                    "<select class='start-minute front'>" +
                        "<option value='' disable selected>minutes </option>" +
                        "<option value='00'>00</option>" +
                        "<option value='15'>15</option>" +
                        "<option value='30'>30</option>" +
                        "<option value='45'>45</option>" +
                    "</select>" +
                "</div>" +
            "</div>" +
        "</div>" +
        "<div class='row'>" +
            "<div class='col s4'>" +
                "<p class='white-text'>Shift Ends at:</p>" +
                "<div class='row'>" +
                    "<div class='input-field col s6'>" +
                        "<select class='start-hour front'>" +
                            "<option value='' disable selected>Hour</option>" +
                            "<option value='00'>12am</option>" +
                            "<option value='01'>1am</option>" +
                            "<option value='02'>2am</option>" +
                            "<option value='03'>3am</option>" +
                            "<option value='04'>4am</option>" +
                            "<option value='05'>5am</option>" +
                            "<option value='06'>6am</option>" +
                            "<option value='07'>7am</option>" +
                            "<option value='08'>8am</option>" +
                            "<option value='09'>9am</option>" +
                            "<option value='10'>10am</option>" +
                            "<option value='11'>11am</option>" +
                            "<option value='12'>12pm</option>" +
                            "<option value='13'>1pm</option>" +
                            "<option value='14'>2pm</option>" +
                            "<option value='15'>3pm</option>" +
                            "<option value='16'>4pm</option>" +
                            "<option value='17'>5pm</option>" +
                            "<option value='18'>6pm</option>" +
                            "<option value='19'>7pm</option>" +
                            "<option value='20'>8pm</option>" +
                            "<option value='21'>9pm</option>" +
                            "<option value='22'>10pm</option>" +
                            "<option value='23'>11pm</option>" +
                        "</select>" +
                   "</div>" +
                    "<div class='input-field col s6'>" +
                        "<select class='start-minute front'>" +
                            "<option value='' disable selected>minutes </option>" +
                            "<option value='00'>00</option>" +
                            "<option value='15'>15</option>" +
                            "<option value='30'>30</option>" +
                            "<option value='45'>45</option>" +
                        "</select>" +
                    "</div>" +
                "</div>" +
            "</div>" +
        "</div>" +
        "<div class='row'>" +
           "<div class='col s8 offset-s2'>" +
                "<p class='white-text'>Number Of Employees Needed:</p>" +
                "<input id='numOfEmployees' type='text'>" +
                "<label for='numOfEmployees'># Of Employees</label>" +
            "</div>" +
       "</div>" +
    "</div>");

    $("#add-shift").append(newShift);
```

Why would I be having trouble adding selects like this??

Comment: Your first select tag has some quote mark confusion happening.

Comment: You will want to look into some html templating eg Handlebars or React

Comment: Ah this was old code, I just updated it

Comment: Was the extra ' the issue?

Answer (score 0):

There's an extra `'` after `shiftStart` in:

```
"<select id='shiftStart'" + numOfShifts + "' class='start-hour front'>"
```